# How to format the printing of doubles

Tags: java, format

Im making a division table from 1-10 an the results range from integers to x.x to x.xx i used decimalformat to keep the the numbers to 2 decimal places but that throws off the format of the table. How would i print the numbers so that they would all be x.xx

```
for example
1 -> 1.00
0.5 -> 0.50
0.333... -> 0.33

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.println("     1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10");
for(double i=1;i<=10;i++){
  System.out.print(df.format(i)+"  ");
  if (i<10) System.out.print(" ");
  else System.out.print("");
  for(double j=1;j<=10;j++){
    double div=(j/i);
    System.out.print(df.format(div));
    if (div < 10) System.out.print("   ");
  }
  System.out.println();

this prints
   1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
2   0.5   1   1.5   2   2.5   3   3.5   4   4.5   5   
3   0.33   0.67   1   1.33   1.67   2   2.33   2.67   3   3.33   
4   0.25   0.5   0.75   1   1.25   1.5   1.75   2   2.25   2.5   
5   0.2   0.4   0.6   0.8   1   1.2   1.4   1.6   1.8   2   
6   0.17   0.33   0.5   0.67   0.83   1   1.17   1.33   1.5   1.67   
7   0.14   0.29   0.43   0.57   0.71   0.86   1   1.14   1.29   1.43   
8   0.12   0.25   0.38   0.5   0.62   0.75   0.88   1   1.12   1.25   
9   0.11   0.22   0.33   0.44   0.56   0.67   0.78   0.89   1   1.11   
10  0.1   0.2   0.3   0.4   0.5   0.6   0.7   0.8   0.9   1   

i want to print everything as x.xx or neatly in columns 
1 1.00 2.00 3.00 4.00 5.00 6.00 7.00 8.00 9.00  10.0
2 0.50 1.00 1.50 2.00 2.50 3.00 3.50 4.00 4.50  5.00
3 0.33 0.67 1.00 1.33 1.67 2.00 2.33 2.67 3.00  3.33
etc
```

Comment: You state that you used DecimalFormat wrong, but don't show us how you tried to use it, nor how your attempt didn't work. Please fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways, but one is to use `String.format("%.2f", myDouble)` Another way is to use a DecimalFormat such as `DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#0.00")` and then use it like `format.format(myDouble)`

To format a table, use `String.format(...)` or one of its variants like printf.

e.g.

```
public class Foo2 {
   private static final int COLS = 10;
   private static final int ROWS = 10;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.printf("%2s", "");
      for (int i = 0; i < COLS; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%8d", (i + 1));
      }
      System.out.println();
      for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
         int row = i + 1;
         System.out.printf("%2d", row);
         for (int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++) {
            double myDouble = (double) row / (j + 1);
            System.out.printf("%8.2f", myDouble);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

which prints out

```
         1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10
 1    1.00    0.50    0.33    0.25    0.20    0.17    0.14    0.13    0.11    0.10
 2    2.00    1.00    0.67    0.50    0.40    0.33    0.29    0.25    0.22    0.20
 3    3.00    1.50    1.00    0.75    0.60    0.50    0.43    0.38    0.33    0.30
 4    4.00    2.00    1.33    1.00    0.80    0.67    0.57    0.50    0.44    0.40
 5    5.00    2.50    1.67    1.25    1.00    0.83    0.71    0.63    0.56    0.50
 6    6.00    3.00    2.00    1.50    1.20    1.00    0.86    0.75    0.67    0.60
 7    7.00    3.50    2.33    1.75    1.40    1.17    1.00    0.88    0.78    0.70
 8    8.00    4.00    2.67    2.00    1.60    1.33    1.14    1.00    0.89    0.80
 9    9.00    4.50    3.00    2.25    1.80    1.50    1.29    1.13    1.00    0.90
10   10.00    5.00    3.33    2.50    2.00    1.67    1.43    1.25    1.11    1.00
```

Comment: decimalformat(#0.00) will print the 10 as 10.00 instead of the 10.0 i want

Comment: @Abe_23: no, you don't want to do that. Stick with two digits after the decimal, and instead format the output so that the numbers line up. You have not yet shown in your original question the current state of your output and your **desired output**, and this is key.

Comment: Thanks to you i now know how to use printf