# java How to check if math result is measurable?

Tags: java, numbers

I would like to check if the result is measurable; that is, whether it has a finite number if decimal places. What do i mean?

```
double x = 5.0 / 9.0; // x = 0.(5)
```

x is not measurable.
I want to round x to the second digit ( x = 0.56 ), but in such case:

```
double x = 1.0 / 8.0; // x = 0.125
```

I don't want to round anything.
So here is my question. How do i decide if the result can be measured or not?

Comment: Do you mean if the number is a terminating decimal?

Comment: Yes, sorry for this English, but it's quite hard to translate such specific words from a native language.

Comment: Can you clarify the cases here, specifically what not measurable means?

Comment: Please explain measurable and non measurable in your case for better understanding.

Comment: @Grzyboo: If you consider 0.1 to be "measurable" (terminating decimal expansion), you will have trouble with `double`.

Comment: infinite decimals and terminating decimals*
0.55555555555... - these ones i want to "cut"

Comment: There are no infinite decimals with double. Ever. By definition. Because double is a limited precision type. If you want to format output, look here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310356)

Comment: Mathematically, 5/9 is a repeating decimal.  However, you can construct `double`s for `5.0/9.0` (repeating?) and `5555555555555556.0 / 10000000000000000.0` (terminating?) that can be compared with `==` with a result of `true`.  You can't tell.

Comment: The reason I can do that is the limited precision of `double`s; they're IEEE floating-point numbers.  The representation is already inexact.  In fact all IEEE floating-point values are terminating decimals.  The fives (or the equivalent mantissa bits in IEEE) must end in the representation.

Comment: Will the numerator and the denominator always be whole numbers?  If so, you should reduce the fraction to simplest form, and find the prime factorisation of the denominator.  The quotient will be a terminating decimal if and only if the only primes in the prime factorisation of the denominator are 2 and 5.  If the numerator and denominator are not guaranteed to be whole numbers, then this problem is far more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. That is the reason, why `1.0 / 3 / 100 * 3 * 100` gives you `0.9999...9`. You only have so many bits to represent the numbers. You cannot distinguish between the period 
`1.0 / 3` and a number that actually has `0.3333.....3` as value

Answer (score 0):

The only fractions which will be exactly represented in a binary will be ones where the denominator is a power of two. If your input is two integers for the numerator and denominator then find the prime factorisation of both and remove the common factors. Then check the only remaining factors on the denominator are power of 2. Say if we want to find 56 / 70 this is 2^3 * 7 / ( 2 * 5 * 7) removing common factors gives 2^2 / 5 so that will not work. But 63 / 72 = (7*3^2) / (2^3 * 3^2) = 7 / 2^3 so will be a terminating binary number

If your working in decimal then powers of 2 and 5 on the denominator will be allowed.